# How Lagom services consume other services?

Tags: microservices, service-discovery, lagom

I can't think in three cases.

1. Lagom service consumes another Lagom service in the same cluster
2. Lagom service consumes another Lagom service in a different cluster
3. Lagom service consumes an external non-Lagom service
4. An external non-Lagom service consumes a Lagom service

**1. Lagom service consumes another Lagom service in the same cluster**

For this case the approach is that ServiceAImpl depends on the ServiceB API, which is binded to a concrete implementation that will be injected to ServiceAImpl.

[ServiceB binding:](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/ServiceClients.html#Binding-a-service-client)

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.server.ServiceGuiceSupport;
import docs.services.HelloService;

public class Module extends AbstractModule implements ServiceGuiceSupport {

    protected void configure() {
        bindClient(HelloService.class);
    }
}
```

[ServiceA implementation:](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/ServiceClients.html#Using-a-service-client)

```
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  private final HelloService helloService;

  @Inject
  public MyServiceImpl(HelloService helloService) {
    this.helloService = helloService;
  }

  @Override
  public ServiceCall<NotUsed, NotUsed, String> sayHelloLagom() {
    return (id, msg) -> {
      CompletionStage<String> response = helloService.sayHello().invoke("Lagom");
      return response.thenApply(answer ->
          "Hello service said: " + answer
      );
    };
  }
}
```

If I understand it correctly, in order to consume the service API in this way, both clients must be in the same cluster.
However Lagom [says](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/Cluster.html#Cluster-composition) that

> A cluster should only span nodes that are running the same service.

In this case we have two different types of services.

- "The same service" means a top level service whose API is exposed to external services?
- In Lagom 1 Microservice = 1 service with external API + n internal services?

**2. Lagom service consumes another Lagom service in a different cluster**

The documentation [says](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/ServiceLocator.html#Integrating-with-external-Lagom-projects):

> Note that if the service you want to communicate with is actually a Lagom service, you may want to read the documentation for [integrating with an external Lagom projects](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/MultipleBuilds.html).

Why is only configured the dependency to the service API and not the IP and port of the external Lagom service also?

**3. Lagom service consumes an external non-Lagom service**

> The first thing you will have to do is to register each external
> service in the Service Locator. Assume we want to register an external
> service named weather that is running on http://localhost:3333, here
> is what we would add to the build:

> ```
>  lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("weather" -> "http://localhost:3333")
> ```

What is the contract with that IP? What should be behind it?

**4. An external non-Lagom service consumes a Lagom service**

I have to use the [Third-Party Registration Pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/3rd-party-registration.html) until Lagom support the [self registration pattern](http://microservices.io/patterns/self-registration.html)?

Comment: I find your question, so confusing...

Comment: agree that many of the hight level Lagom docs discuss decoupled services, while deployment conveys simplicity of 1 cluster....

Answer (score 2):

When Lagom talks about "cluster", it's referring to Akka clusters.  Each service may be deployed as an Akka cluster, that is, a service may be a cluster of nodes.  So you don't have multiple services in a cluster, you just have one clustered service.

Lagom service calls map down in a fairly straight forward fashion to idiomatic REST.  So, when talking to an external service, the thing at that IP should be a REST service.  Likewise, when an external service is talking to Lagom, it should use REST.

Comment: Thanks for answer @James. In the case of point (1), isn't HelloService  running in the same cluster as MyServiceImpl?